# How can I use Angular to build a recipe blog / website

Tags: angular, blogs

I want to create a blog to store and present my recipes. As I want to improve my skills in Angular, I thought it would be best to use Angular for the development.

From a conceptual point of view, I am not sure how to structure the project.

I want to store each recipe with a phot in a Postgres database.

I would like to have a start page that shows a grid with the title +  thumbnail of each recipe, which should be able to be filtered by category. 
Selecting one recipe should show a detailed page with the description and multiple photos of the recipe.

Would it be sufficient to have two components, one for the start page and one for a detailed view? And then showing the content via filtered database queries based on the user selection (category on startpage, recipe id on detailed page)? Any other ideas or approaches?

Comment: Assuming you don't need any menu page, login page, error redirection page or any other type of 'utility' pages, you can achieve what you described with only 2 components (+ the default app.component). Although you should think whether you will want to add extra functionality later on, in which case you should try and make your app scalable using proper routing, services (or even splitting it into modules but that shouldn't be necessary for a small blog).

Comment: Extra note: The tour of heroes from the official website: https://angular.io/tutorial is very close to what you want: display a list of item in one component, go to a detail view of each component in another component. Now it's just a matter of using your own database instead of mockup data

Answer (score 0):

It is a good way to split components into the small pieces. Because you can even code your big application in the single AppComponent. But don't do this :)

I suggest you just to start coding it since you are new to Angular. Then, try to refactor it in a more comfortable way to you

By the way, Angular is not the best tool for JAM stack right now.
You can choose a more lightweight and flexible tool like a Svelte